# How to set filename for zwcreatefile function?

Tags: c, kernel, createfile

Suppose I want to open file  `c:/test.txt`
That's how I do it at the moment, and it does not work:

```
RtlInitUnicodeString(&uniName, L"\\SystemRoot\\test.txt");  // 
    InitializeObjectAttributes(&obj_atr, &uniName,
        OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE /*| OBJ_KERNEL_HANDLE*/,
        NULL, NULL);
 ntStatus = ZwCreateFile(&handle,
            GENERIC_WRITE,
            &obj_atr, &result, NULL,
            FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
            0,
            FILE_OPEN,
            FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT,
            NULL, 0);
```

Comment: Any feedback on my answer? Did it help? The grace period on the bounty is about to expire. If it expires and mine is the only answer - without at least two votes, being selected as the answer, or being chosen as the recipient of the bounty - nobody will get the bounty. https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty

Comment: For the record, none of the bounty was awarded to anyone.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-open-a-file-from-a-kernel-mode-device-driver-and-how-to-read-from-or-write-to-the-file-45f7de35-cac4-8d83-9520-a7e480ca404d), "The \SystemRoot namespace is mapped to the folder where the operation system is installed. For example, this folder may be C:\Windows or D:\Winnt."

So `L"\\SystemRoot\\test.txt"` will map to **C:\Windows\test.txt** and not **C:\test.txt**.

Alternatively, you can try `L"\\DosDevices\\C:\\test.txt"`, but the same page notes that, "If the device driver is loaded early, the \DosDevices namespace may not yet exist."